# tab content handling.... how in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

i have a tabactivity with two tabs.

in this tabactivity i have edittext and button to search the local database.

i have a listactivity class as a tabcontent. it shows by the framelayout.

i want to refresh that listactivity based on the text entered in edittext which is in the tabactivity.

how to do that?

i created a method in a listactivity :

```
public void search(String temp) {
String val=temp;
try{
c=BruTube_Videos.this.getContentResolver().query(Constants.CONTENT_URI, null, Constants.TITLE+" like '%"+val+"%'", null, "DATETIME("+Constants.PUBLISHED+") DESC");
}catch(Exception e){
Log.v(TAG, "exp in cursor");
}
show(c);
}
```

invoke this method in a tabactivity like this:

```
EditText et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
String temp=et1.getText().toString();
BruTube_Videos vdo_obj=new BruTube_Videos();
vdo_obj.search(temp);
```

it shows an exception in logcat:

02-12 16:58:26.623: VERBOSE/BruTube_Videos(227): Exception in brutube search:java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

how can i manage it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BruTube_Videos vdo_obj=new BruTube_Videos();
```

Never call a constructor on an `Activity`. You never create activities -- you tell Android to start them. That is the source of your error.

I strongly encourage you to get rid of the activities altogether, and have a single `TabActivity` holding onto `Views` -- one that is a layout for your edit form, one that is your `ListView`. Then, you will not get confused as to where the code goes, since there is only one activity. This is also more efficient from a programming, memory, CPU, and battery utilization standpoint.

Comment: hi thanks for reply.. i have customized layouts for a single list item. so i must be use the customized simpleCursorAdapter. how can i use a cursoradapter in listview. give me some code examples.

Comment: Can anyone provide some code detailing how to do this?  It's not clear how to do this, even using views.